# Wordpress Query 'orderby' => 'meta_value' lists 10 before 9

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress site for my father in law's restaurant. Each course has a number that I list using 'orderby' of a advanced custom field containing a number.

In the segment with numbers 6-10 the number 10 shows up as the first element, and I would like it to show up after 9.

Every other segment works just fine.

Example:

-Segment-
1
2
3
4
5
-Segment-
10
6
7
8
9
-Segment-
11
12
13

This is my query.

```
<?php
// The Query
 query_posts( array (

    'category_name' => 'example',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'number',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    ) );
?>

 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 Content


 <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that you made meta_value a char or varchar, not an int field. In character (alphabetical) ordering, 10 comes before 9 because 1 comes before 9.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

By removing:
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',

I was able to order just by 'asc'.

```
<?php
// The Query
 query_posts( array (

    'category_name' => 'example',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'number',
    'order' => 'ASC'
    ) );
?>

 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 Content


 <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```